# ThreadPoolExecutor configuration

Tags: java

I have a situation where I expect adding to the thread pool to be faster than processing. I don't think an unbounded queue will be a good idea because there is enough data that the queue might grow to eat all memory if left unchecked. Given this I'm trying to determine the correct setup for a ThreadPoolExecutor.

My first thought is a fixed thread pool with direct handoff and caller runs failure policy. But I wonder if this will hurt throughput (because every time caller runs policy is invoked the thread pool tasks will likely complete and sit idle for some time).

Another idea is fixed thread pool with ArrayBlockingQueue, but I'm actually not sure of the behavior of that. I'm hoping it means that the Executor prefers creating threads if less than coreThread size, then queues, and if the queue is full it blocks waiting for the queue to get space. But in reading the docs here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

It seems that it will prefer creating threads up to corePoolSize, then add to the queue, and if the queue is full it will try creating threads up to maxThreads (same as coreThreads in this case), and failing that it will run the failure policy.

Can someone clarify the behavior for the case above? And also suggest what the best setup might be for this particular case (one of my suggested ideas or some other one that might work better)?

Comment: For your use case, I suggest you test it.  What is best depends on the throughput you want to sustain, and the latency of each task.  A thread pool can easily handle in the order of one million tasks per second (provided the tasks are trivial). Do you have option to slow the producer if it is too fast?

Comment: the consumer is posting data to a webservice, and the producer is just  reading records out of a file. So hopefully you can see why the producer is fast and the consumer is slow. If I let the producer keep adding to a queue I'll run out of memory. So I'm hoping there's a way to nicely configure ThreadPoolExecutor to do the throttling for me (as in my first example CallerRunsPolicy is a crude form of throttling). Ideally there's a way to make the producer block waiting for space in the queue, when max threads are utilized and the queue is full.

Comment: I would have the producer pause whenever the queue length exceeds some length. (This is the length of waiting jobs) This way you can be sure it will never get too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure I make this another answer because its a different solution to the same problem.

You can use just a ThreadPoolExecutor and Semaphore. The semaphore would be created with the max number you want to allow in the queue and after each thread finishes execution, you would invoke release (beforeExecute, which is when the item is pulled off the queue)

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1000);
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5,10,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()){
  protected void beforeExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) { 
     semaphore.release();
  }
}

public void doSubmit(Runnable r){
  sempahore.acquire();
  executor.submit(r);      
}
```

So here all threads will suspend until there is a permit available (entry on the queue).

Comment: This works; I guess I was hoping that since ArrayBlockingQueue is documented to block when put() is called on a full queue, that simply using an ArrayBlockingQueue would produce the desired behavior (it would certainly be nicer if this type of functionality was built in).

Comment: Yea, this question has been raised before, the first time I saw it I was as surprised as you are the functionality is not available in some form.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I actually implemented a descendant of java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor, which:
- throws UnsupportedOperationException in setMaxPoolSize to prevent Semaphor changes
- has a semaphor member with the same maximum number as maxpoolsize, initialized by constructors
- queue is always an unbounded linkedblockingqueue
- afterExecute method is overridden, and releases a semaphor
- all submits acquire a semaphore
Works perfectly. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

The ThreadPoolExecutor will create more threads then when all threads are currently being used.  That means the queue can be empty but if all threads are running previous tasks, a new task will create a new thread up until the maximum is reached.

If the queue is full and the threads are all saturated the ThreadPoolExecutor will actually reject the task and throw a `RejectedExecutionException`.  So using a BlockingQueue will not actually have the expected results.

If you want to throttle the number of tasks that are currently in the queue you can use an ExecutorCompletionService and the backing queue.

```
//core 5 max 10 with 60 second idle time
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5,10,60,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
ExecutorCompletionService completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);
private final static int MAX_IN_QUEUE = 1000; 

public void doSubmit(Runnable r){
    while(executor.getQueue().size() >= MAX_IN_QUEUE) 
       completionService.poll(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    completionService.submit(r);
}
```

This has the noticeable side effect of having to continuously wait for an element to complete.  I loop on the condition because of the possible race condition of the while actually being true immateriality after entering the block.

And of course the race condition of multiple submits, but it should throttle enough to prevent overcrowding of the queue. This can be solved by simply synchronizing the `doSubmit` method.

Answer (score 0):

If a single thread is making all the requests, then an unbounded queue will block as you like without the negative side-effect of queue growth.

If multiple threads make the requests, then the fixed pool with caller runs policy should work as you want. The remaining threads in the pool will be kept active by the other requesting threads.

Comment: There is a single producer thread and N consumer threads. How does that prevent queue growth when using an unbounded queue? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I should have stipulated the use of caller runs policy in this case as well. Since the caller (producer) runs and there is only one of him, the queue can not grow while he is busy executing the request.

Comment: but wouldn't unbounded queue mean that the failure policy is never called? I agree with either direct handoff or bounded queue the caller runs policy would work.

Comment: I see. I think you are correct. I now see what you mean. With a single producer thread, you are forced to choose between unbounded queue growth or potentially underutilized threads while caller runs. Good post.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the producer pause whenever the queue length gets too long.

Something like this limits the size of the queue of waiting tasks to a MAX_LEN.

```
ExecutorService service = 
Queue workQ = // queue of service.
BufferedReader br =
String line;
while((line = br.readline()) != null) {
    service.submit(new ProcessLineRunnable(line));
    while(workQ.size() > MAX_LEN) Thread.sleep(1);
}
```