# How to solve Java error "pool-1-thread-xxxx" java.lang.OutOfMemory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, threadpool

I have searched the posts about this issue, but I did't see similar situation like mine.

My java console shows the error message `"pool-1-thread-xxxx" java.lang.OutOfMemory` as the picture bellow:

[image: pool-1-thread-OutOfMemoryError issuse]

[image: performance monitor]

- Red Line: CPU usage
- Green line: Memory usage

I have increased the RAM from `6G` to `10G`, and set `-Xms=8G -Xmx=8G -Xmn=3G` in `*.bat` file before I start the program. I also keep watching performance monitor but the memory is always around 20%. I have no idea how could this happen. Any idea?

Here is my `run.bat` code.

```
@echo off 
javapro @java -Xoptimize -Xms8G -Xmx8G -Xmn3G -Xss1024k -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -cp javaPro.exe;
cls
run.bat
```

- OS: windows server 2012 R2
- Java version : jre1.8.0_171
- RAM: 10G
- CPU: 2.5 GHz Intel Xeon(R)(Hyper Threaded)

Comment: Could you give the code of your the thread pool?

Comment: Hard to say anything w/o actual code. Your thread number on the `pool-1` is `1395`, so you have at least 1395 threads running. The message `OOM: unable to create native thread` means that there're no free system resources to allocate new thread. Please post some code, maybe you're using `CachedThreadPoolExecutor` there but the tasks are not short enough, so the system blows up. See more on [OOM explanation here](https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/understanding-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: You seem to create many threads in your application. You should show us the main code you try to execute, you may have something wrong there, and not related with your memory configuration. Is it expected to create so many new threads in what you are trying to do with your application ?

Comment: Check this https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the source code. Is that possible to increase thread pool limitation?

Comment: I found that windows server only allocates 1024MB to virtual memory, I'll increase it to 4G and see what will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` means that

> the JVM is asking a new thread from the OS and the underlying OS
>   cannot allocate a new thread anymore.

See [OOM explanations](https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/understanding-java-lang-outofmemoryerror) and [your specific case explained](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread).

So you won't see high memory usage in the graph, because the heap size is not close to its limit.

You have to check your application code and inspect the thread pool usages there. It's hard to say anything without the source code, but there may be few suggestions:

1. If you use `CachedThreadPoolExecutor`, then the submitted tasks may be not fast enough, so your app is unable to process all submitted tasks.
2. You may use `FixedThreadPoolExecutor` with the maximum (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) capacity, in such case you have to limit the pool capacity and its queue size. So the pool eats all available threads and `OOM` happens.

Generally, you should always control your thread pool configuration and be sure it won't hog all system resources.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the reason. Great answer, thank you.

Comment: @david0116 command `ulimit -a` only displays the soft-limit on a Linux server, while this isn't even a viable solution for a Linux server, even if that second link boldly pretends it would be "the solution" (which it isn't unless adjusting these values).

Comment: @MartinZeitler the `ulimit -a` is an OS level setting, but the error happens in the Java process and likely should be fixed in the same scope. Your answer may solve the problem (I upvoted it), but it won't eliminate the root cause. The Java thread pools should be properly configured in the JVM. I just tried to explain the underlying problem here. The author can check the source code now and fix the actual cause.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev Java cannot reserve any more memory/threads than the OS provides - that's why the maximum utilization is lower than it would be theoretically assigned to JVM. the thread-pool managed by Java can never exceed the OS limits, just alike the OS can never exceed the hardware limits; it's not exactly alike `KVM`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler that's true, but it doesn't mean that you shouldn't put any thread pool or memory limits on the JVM/Java level. Every time your run a Java app you have to take care on heap size and thread pools capacity. If your requirements exceed the OS capabilities, then you should tweak OS params. So the combination of both answers gives the better explanation :)

Comment: Agree with you guys, both answer should be accepted. But MartinZeitler provided Linux solution, I still can't find how to increase thread limitation on windows. So I think @VladimirVagaytsev is more reasonable to be accepted as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

think that I've found a possible reason / solution approach:

one can check for the soft-limit for processes with `ulimit -a`:

```
$ cat /proc/22666/limits | grep processes
Max processes             1024                 62265                processes 

$ ulimit -a | grep processes
max user processes
```

in order to change these values:

```
$ ulimit -Su 2000

$ ulimit -a | grep processes
max user processes (-u) 2000

$ cat /proc/22666/limits | grep processes
Max processes 2000
```

one can also adjust the default configuration:

1. modify the [limits.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/limits.conf.5.html) file with the following:
2. `sudo nano /etc/security/limits.conf` or look inside `/etc/security/limit.d/`.
3. add the following for the user who runs `java`.

**limits.conf**

```
#<domain>        <type>  <item>    <value>

# adjust these values as needed:
someuser          soft    nofile    4096
someuser          hard    nofile    8192
```

then modify the `common-session` file with the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

add the following line:

**common-session**

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

and restart java.

- also see the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/threadpoolexecutor.html) ...
- and the [ThreadPoolExecutor Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329318/threadpoolexecutor-configuration).

for a Windows 2012 Server, this would be about the same.

- see [Pushing the Limits of Windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/07/21/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-physical-memory/) on the Tech Net Blog.

Comment: How about windows server 2012? where is limits.conf file location?

Comment: @david0116 this would be for a Linux server, while Windows 2012 Server ™ should have about the same settings for limits per user (the same Java error message hints for this). see the server management console: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/manage-the-local-server-and-the-server-manager-console if not there, there might be registry keys which hold these limits.

Comment: @david0116 it's probably not a bug, but a system security/stability feature.

Comment: Actually, I think this answer is really close to be accepted. As my error message showed "pool-1-thread-1395", I think 1395 threads is not a normal thread limitation amount. It's limited for some reason like your answer. If you don't mind, may I post a new question for increasing java thread limitation for windows? I still can't find how to do it.