# Android and Node.js: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, node.js, gradle, out-of-memory

So this error has taken two days of work from me. The error started yesterday from nowhere - I was tweaking and testing my code, and in one of my compilations the problem started.

I pulled from the last working project commit - which is currently working in my partner's PC, and the problems still occurred. The thing is a different error pops up on every build attempt. The project is written in Java with Node.js implementations.

This is one of them - the build error description says:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'.
```

Detailed:

```
    org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to obtain compression information for entry
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1260)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:148)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:108)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:132)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:152)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:633)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:663)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:654)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doFullTaskAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:393)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain compression information for entry
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1822)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1761)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.writeFile(ApkZFileCreator.java:158)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateFiles(IncrementalPackager.java:176)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateAssets(IncrementalPackager.java:238)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:666)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.splitFullAction(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:496)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.lambda$doFullTaskAction$2(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:388)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:391)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:125)
    ... 51 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain compression information for entry
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1822)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntriesWithWait(ZFile.java:1836)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.update(ZFile.java:990)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.close(ZFile.java:1283)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.close(ApkZFileCreator.java:189)
        at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:216)
        at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.close(IncrementalPackager.java:332)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact.doTask(PackageAndroidArtifact.java:676)
        ... 62 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1817)
        ... 69 more
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.util.zip.Deflater.init(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.Deflater.<init>(Deflater.java:171)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.compress.DeflateExecutionCompressor.immediateCompress(DeflateExecutionCompressor.java:68)
        at com.android.apkzlib.zip.compress.ExecutorCompressor.lambda$compress$0(ExecutorCompressor.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1817)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.init(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.<init>(Deflater.java:171)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.compress.DeflateExecutionCompressor.immediateCompress(DeflateExecutionCompressor.java:68)
    at com.android.apkzlib.zip.compress.ExecutorCompressor.lambda$compress$0(ExecutorCompressor.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I have tried updating the Gradle distribution to the most recent (4.9-all) by changing the *gradle-wrapper.properties* and downloading the package. I've noticed something wrong happening (also happened on 4.4-all):
[image]
It does *com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeSourceSetFolders$AssetWorkAction* forever (at 18m at the moment as I'm testing), and at some point starts throwing OutOfMemoryError:
[image]

What I've tried:

- Invalidating Caches / Restart... into Clean Project and Rebuild a lot of times;
- Deleting .gradle and .idea from project folder;
- Deleting the project and cloning into a fresh one from repo;
- Reinstalling Android Studio;
- Increasing JVM max memory available in gradle.properties;
- Running Android Studio in administrator mode.

Comment: Do you have parallel builds enabled in Gradle?  If so then try turning that off.  You could also try configuring Gradle to allot more memory to the VM in which it runs (supposing that more is available than it is using).

Comment: No, parallel builds are disabled @JohnBollinger.

Comment: increasing `JVM` memory is useless, when that `java.util.zip.Deflater` is hitting the limit permitted by the OS ...explained that there before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945268/how-to-solve-java-error-pool-1-thread-xxxx-java-lang-outofmemory/51945739#51945739 the latest `Gradle` version is not necessarily always the best choice for Android Studio (here I use 4.5). this might be "opinion based", but "while it works".

Answer (score 0):

We finally solved it!

For anyone who encountered the same error and is using a big Node.js library with many dependencies, we solved the problem by compiling all the Javascript code into one file - it has 128482 lines of code, but the build is way faster and it doesn't throw *OutOfMemoryError*s anymore.

[image]