# How do I increase thread limitation on windows server?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, threadpool, windows-server

According to  [How to solve Java error "pool-1-thread-xxxx" java.lang.OutOfMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945268/how-to-solve-java-error-pool-1-thread-xxxx-java-lang-outofmemory). As far as I known, there are two directions to solve the problem. Either optimize source code or increase thread limitation. I don't have the source code. I think increase thread limitation is the only way that I could try. I've been searching the answer for a while, but still can't find a correct way to do it. My OS is 64 bit windows server 2012. That means it has default of 1MB reserved for stack. After I read this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/, I'm totally confused for the thread limitation. There are some points I don't understand:

1. The error message shows "pool-1-thread-1395". Why is the limit amount only 1395 threads? I thought it should be a lot more than it.
2. I also read some information about virtual memory. That may affects thread limitation. I found that it has only 1024MB virtual memory for my OS, is that why thread limit so low? (1024MB VM/1MB stack size = 1024 threads)
3. There is a java executing argument -xss. It represents init size of stack. If I set it to 128k, would OS default 1M stack size be changed?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Machine info:

- OS: 64 bit Windows server 2012 R2
- Java version : jre1.8.0_171
- RAM: 10G
- CPU: 2.5 GHz Intel Xeon(R)(Hyper Threaded)

Comment: `pool-1-thread-1395` doesn't mean there's a limit of `1395` threads. All you know is that `thread-1395` in `pool-1` encountered that error. There may be more threads in the pool (or less), and there can be other pools too. If the code is careless with threads, then you might be fighting a losing battle, as increasing anything would just postpone the problem. You should be contacting the developers of that code and talking to them about it.

Comment: Full error message is "pool-1-thread-1395" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. Yes, you are right. I still want to know how to increase limitation of thread on windows. Because the developer has disappear  for years. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. You can fit tens of thousands of threads in `10GB`, so that's not your problem. You should be analyzing the Java software and seeing what it's doing. What software are you running if I may ask?

Comment: I'm running a small game server. I found that I can see total running threads amount from task manager. It shows 1365 threads now. If I could increase thread limit to at lease 10k. That might temporary solve my problem.

Comment: I don't really think your problem is with thread limits, but I don't work with Windows servers often these days either, so I can't really help you on that account. My comments were from a Java point of view, but you don't seem to want to concentrate on that side. Also, if you see 1365 running threads in the task manager, that doesn't tell you anything about the max amount of threads. It sounds like you're jumping to conclusions based on numbers you see, thinking they mean more than they do (like the thread named `pool-1-thread-1395`). Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Before I moved the game server to GCP, I never encounter the issue like that. I think there are some limits on windows server 2012(was windows 7). I have tried to change windows server virtual memory from 1024mb to 2048mb, the error message hasn't been showing up almost 2 days. I will  keep watching the server log see if the error still happen. Before that, I just want to know what is the right way to increase thread limit for windows server 2012.

Comment: Yes, rewrite source code is the best way to do, but I can't solve the problem from java side. What I have is only an executable file(game.exe). There is nothing I can do with source code.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting rewriting the source code, don't be silly. I also don't understand what you're talking about. You said you "changed the virtual memory from 1GB to 2GB"? I thought you had 10GB of memory?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language. Maybe something misunderstood.You wanted my to concentrate on java. All I have known is something causes out of memory and can't create new native threads. I don't know what else I could do. I just need to solve the problem immediately.

Comment: I tried to do something from OS level, seems working. Increase thread limits might solve my problem, so I think I could work with it first. I'm not familiar with virtual memory, I just simply choose "Automatically manage...."  let system decided for me. I don't know why it only gave me 2G(from default 1G to 2G) for virtual memory. On my local computer(win 7), it assigned like 16G for virtual memory, that equals to my physical memory.

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about the size of the [swap file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) (Page File in windows terms)? Virtual memory is basically physical memory + swap, so in a server with `10GB` of physical memory, you would have *at least* `10GB` of virtual memory. If the server requires more memory, you'll need more memory or a bigger swap file.

Comment: Yes, it's swap file. There is "Virtual memory" on the setting window. According to https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2016/05/10/how-to-manage-windows-10-virtual-memory.aspx I thought 2G is virtual memory, RAM+Virtual memory = total memory? However, my game server seems not to occur the error anymore...that's weird. I did two changes for it. 1. Increased virtual memory from 1G to 2G. 2. Removed java starting up argument -xss. it was -xss1024k(But 64bit windows default stack size is 1MB, too). Thank you for your patience in helping a newbie.

Comment: You can safely increase the swap to more than `2GB`. Commonly the swap is the same size as the physical memory, so you could have `20GB` total memory. It just means that if your programs are using a lot of memory, they might end up "thrashing", when memory gets paged in and out constantly. In that case you need more physical memory to keep up a good performance.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.